# Payment for Orphan blocks

Tags: blockchain

I know that miners don't get paid for orphan blocks. But what do they not get paid , transaction fees or block reward or both ?

Comment: Orphan blocks, for all purposes, may have never happened at all.  So Orphan blocks pay nothing. (No transaction fees, nor block reward fees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are paid nothing. An orphan block is wasted time and energy. A miner must put some effort into maintaining good connectivity to all the other nodes to avoid wasting money.

Comment: Is it that a miner gets paid for the creation of a block after 6 confirmations in case of bitcoin?

Comment: A miner in every cryptocurrency gets paid in the very same block they mine. In case of Bitcoin they only can spend it 100 blocks later.